# How to change ci_method to "wald" in a logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, sjplot

I need to run a logistic regression on a dataset with approximately 1,000,000 data points.
I ran a model

```
logit_results <<- glm(y ~ p1 + p2 + p3,
                      data = df,family="binomial", 
                      na.action = "na.exclude")
```

I want to visualise the results using the  `plot_model()` function

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_x <- plot_model(logit_results,vline.color = "#1EA891",sort.est = TRUE,title="Graph")
```

This is taking forever to run (I've been waiting for about an hour, and it hasn't finished). I get a message `` Profiled confidence intervals may take longer time to compute. Use `ci_method="wald"` for faster computation of CIs. ``
However, I don't know where to change the ci_method, as neither `the glm()` or `plot_model()` use `ci_method` .

Anyone knows how might I change the ci_method to "wald"?

Answer (score 4):

This message comes from the `parameters` package, which is a dependency from `sjPlot` package. If we look at the source code from `tidy_model` in `sjPlot` (I looked it up from [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/cran/sjPlot/src/R/tidiers.R) but I think we can do something like `sjPlot:::tidy_model`), then we would find the following code:

```r
if (is.null(p.val)) {
      if (inherits(model, c("glm", "polr"))) {
        p.val <- "profile"
      } else {
        p.val <- "wald"
      }
    }
```

This means if `p.val` is not specified and the model comes from glm or polr, then p.val is profile, which later on translates to ci_method="profile", else ci_method would be "wald".

So this becomes pretty obvious, all we have to do is to specify `p.val="wald"`:

```r
plot_x <- plot_model(logit_results,vline.color = "#1EA891",
      sort.est = TRUE,title="Graph",p.val="wald")
```